# VS Code / Code Spaces can not change font size

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I am experimenting with [GH Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces)
in my local VS Code (I know it's running remote).

However somehow I can not change the font size.
`Ctrl + ,` for preferences, I found the Editor: font size option,
however, changing it does not impact the font size.

[image]

When I just try the same thing without codespaces (locally) it works just fine.
Is this enough to be reported as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for this issue.

1. Open up the Command Palette (Shift + Cmd + P).
2. Search for 'Editor Font Zoom Out'/ 'Editor Font Zoom Out' and select
   either option until you reach your desired font size.

[Gif of Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK66m.gif)

Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

Came here for the same problem and found out there is a hidden tab on settings.

This is the proper way of doing it. The default was 22.

[image]